# Matlab: increase precision of command "importdata"

Tags: file-io, precision, data-import

i am having a problem with matlab. I am trying to import some data in a matlab code and i use the command "importdata" but i can't get the desired precision.

this is a small part of the txt which name is "NACA 0008":

```
NACA 0008 Airfoil M=0.0% P=0.0% T=8.0%
1.000000  0.000840
0.996057  0.001208
0.984292  0.002295
0.964888  0.004055
```

and part of my matlab code is this but when i display coord.data 
the variables saved in the array are these:

```
coord = importdata('NACA 0008.txt'); %read coordinates for airfoil from "NACA 0008.txt"
disp(coord.data);

1.0000    0.0008
0.9961    0.0012
0.9843    0.0023
0.9649    0.0041
```

how can i increase the precision to which I want my data loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `format longG;` before importing codes, like this:

```matlab
format longG;
ImportFile('data.txt');
```

or run `format longG` in Command Window before import command.